# I'm unable to find a previous date by inputing a given date by a user using html and javascript. Can you please help me out

Tags: javascript, html

'This is the HTML Code'

```
<form>
  <div class="input-field">
    <label>Choose Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="date" onchange="myDate();" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-fields">
    <label>Previous Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="previous" readonly>
  </div>
</form>
```

'This is the Javascript Code'

```
<script>
    function myDate()
      {
      const currDate = document.getElementById("date");
      const date = new Date(currDate)
      if (typeof date === 'object' && date !== null && 'getDate' in date) {
      console.log("The data type is", typeof date)
      console.log(date.getDate())}
      else {
        console.log("Invalid Date Object")
      }
      date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
      const previous = document.write(date);
      document.getElementById("previous").value = previous;
      }
</script>
```

I'm trying to get previous date by using the myDate Function in Javascript and i was getting an error getDate is not a function then i tried to make getDate as function and now its showing the same error. I'm not able to make a getDate as function or getting previous date value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with `new Date(currDate)` this here you create new date with `element` so you need to do `new Date(currDate.value)` then you need to format date according to what date picker accept `yyyy-MM-DD`.

```js
function myDate() {
  const currDate = document.getElementById("date");
  const date = new Date(currDate.value)
  if (typeof date === 'object' && date !== null && 'getDate' in date) {
    console.log("The data type is", typeof date)
    console.log(date.getDate())
  }
  else {
    console.log("Invalid Date Object")
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  document.getElementById("previous").value = formateDate(date);
}

function formateDate(d) {
    return  d.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2)  ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Choose Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" onchange="myDate();" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-fields">
      <label>Previous Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="previous">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cLzy2sa1/) is the solution for you.

First problem that you had is that you got the element in `currDate` instead of the value.

After that, I don't understand what you were trying to do on your `previous` variable but you where overwriting the actual `DOM` with the updated date.

Last, you have to convert the date that you want to set on the other field to the accepted string, so you need to truncate the `toISOString()` method to return the date in format of `YYYY-MM-DD` (since that is how you read if from the initial input).

```js
function myDate()
{
  const currDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
  const date = new Date(currDate)
  
  if (typeof date === 'object' && date !== null && 'getDate' in date) {
    console.log("The data type is", typeof date)
    console.log(date.getDate())}
  else {
    console.log("Invalid Date Object")
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
  document.getElementById("previous").value = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```